# Using Cash on delivery payment, ordered product not able to cancel in magento admin panel, cancel button is missing

Tags: php, email, paypal, magento-1.9

Am suing cash on delivery payment method, Orders product are not able to cancel from admin panel can anyone help me.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can not cancel orders placed using the Cash on Delivery payment method from the admin Sales->Orders->View ?

Comment: but , in other project cancel button is available to cancel order place by Cash on delivery. Cancel button only missing from my project,, if we place order by using credit card or online payment, then am able to cancel the order , if i cancel order the qty is re-adding to product.

Comment: Okay! Have you or someone else perhaps edited mage core functionality? Say the Mage_Sales_Model_Order class and especially the canCancel method ? I'm almost sure the solution to your problem lies there.